# How to avoid using ++ and -- operators

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

Ok, I have the code done in a way that works great and uses the increment ++ and decrement -- operators.

```
unsigned int atob(const char* input)
{

    int i = 0;

    while (input[i] == '0' || input[i] == '1') i++;

    unsigned result = 0;
    unsigned currentBit = --i;

    while ((*input == '0') || (*input == '1')) {
        char isCurrentBitSet = *input == '1';
        unsigned setValue = (isCurrentBitSet << currentBit--);
        result |= setValue;
        input++;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Now, I need to get rid of all dec(--)/inc(++) except for input++ at the bottom of the while statement. I am baffled at how to do this implementation.

Comment: What is the reason you need to get rid of the increment and decrement?

Comment: @EvilTeach: I'm just guessing, but I'd say it was his teacher (professor, whatever) indirectly trying to nudge him toward considering a different solution.

Comment: Somewhat close. I am just doing it for study though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go:

```
unsigned int atob(const char* input)
{
  unsigned result = 0;

  while ((*input == '0') || (*input == '1')) {
    result = (result << 1) | (*input++ - '0');
  }

  return result;
}
```

Saves some stack space too :)

Answer (score 2):

The usual way is to start with your result set to 0. Then for each character of input, shift the result left one bit, `or` in the current bit, and repeat until you reach the end of the input string (or something other than a `0` or `1`, anyway).

Answer (score 1):

Decided to drastically change my solution:

```
unsigned int atob(const char* input)
{
    unsigned val; 

    for (val = 0; *input; input++) {
        if (*input == '1') val = (val << 1) | 1;
        else if (*input == '0' ) val <<= 1;
        else break;
    }

    return val;
}
```

Comment: Kind of like this one don't ya think?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310796/binary-to-unsigned-int-using-bitwise-operations-and-pointer-arithmetic-in-c

Answer (score 0):

Replace i++ with i = i + 1?  That seems way to easy.

Comment: Can't use arithmetic at all. So, no.

Comment: Your question should perhaps include that statement? (hint)

Answer (score -1):

Consider replacing the entire function by a call to [strtol](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtol/)